# Why is past simple used in this sentence when it happened before?

Tags: past-tense, past-vs-past-perfect, time-reference

> Philippe Siegfried called me one day in February to announce that he
>   had unpublished titles of his group PANORAMAS. It **was** Emmanuelle
>   Jean-Luc Taccard's wife (LUCAS TROUBLE, TANGO LÜGER ...) who
>   **passed** my contact, I told him that I was looking for unpublished titles for the label.

Why not past perfect for this sentence as it happened before the phone call and it is because Emmanuel had given the contact that the phone call was possible?

Comment: This is a translation and the English is not perfect. I would have said *who had given him*.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the original in French:

> **Un jour de février, j'ai reçu un coup de fil de Philippe Siegfried qui me disait avoir des morceaux inédits de son groupe PANORAMAS (1 > titre inédit figure sur la compilation Thésaurus Volume 4). C'était
> Emmanuelle, l'épouse du regretté Jean-Luc Taccard (Lucas Trouble,
> Tango Lüger…) qui lui *avait passé* mon contact car je lui avais dit que
> c'était le genre de choses que je recherchais pour mon label.**
> [Cameleon Records](http://www.45vinylvidivici.net/ajout/RAJOUT/CAMELEONRECORDS/CAMELEONkamerasFRA.htm)

My translation of bolded text:

One day in February, I **got a call** from Philippe Siegfried who told me he had unreleased pieces by his group Panorama. (One unpublished track is on the compilation Thesaurus Volume 4). It was Emmanuelle, the wife of deceased Jean-Luc Taccard (Lucas Trouble, Tango Lüger, etc.) who **had given my contract** to him because I had told him that it was the type of thing I was looking for, for my label.

[I am a French>English translator]

The French does use the past perfect and the machine or person that translated this text got it all wrong, not just that.

Answer (score 0):

Because the past perfect is usually optional when the sequence of events is clear without it, and there is no requirement to set a temporal focus.

Comment: if I change the sentences     Philippe Siegfried called me one day in February to announce that he had unpublished titles of his group PANORAMAS. Emmanuelle Jean-Luc Taccard's wife (LUCAS TROUBLE, TANGO LÜGER ...)   had given to him my contact, I told him that I was looking for unpublished titles for the label.  Is past perfect optional too in this case: if I don't use PP we can believe that first P called and then E gave to him my contact . Am I right?

Comment: Yes, *had given* is better but there are still a lot of problems with this translation. *Announce* is not the right word. We don't use capitals like that. A comma is required after *Emanuelle*. We don't use ... for *etc.*. It's unlikely that we would say *unpublished titles* for what I think you mean. The choice of tense is not really the issue...